# Hide axis of linked objects?

Tags: linked-data

Is there some way to hide the axis of linked objects?  I'm working on a model that's a composite of a bunch of others and all the crosshairs are making it really difficult to work with as most of the work has to be done in wireframe just to get the positioning right for internal objects. The image below demonstrates the issue:

[image]

Comment: The crosshairs are empty objects, right?

Comment: No, the crosshairs are linked groups from other .blend files.

Comment: Go to Viewport Overlays, and under Objects, click Extras

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to set size of the crosshairs to 0:

[image]

To do this for multiple objects set the active one and copy to all the selected with right-click on property-field and Copy_To_Selected option.

This will only scale them and not eliminate them.

You can also set the *viewport properties panel > Display > Only Render* property:

[image]